# Hibernate: cannot drop foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

Having this two classes:

*Address.java*:

```
@Embeddable
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String pincode;
}
```

*User.java*:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
}
```

*DemoApplication.java*:

```java
@Bean
CommandLineRunner dataLoader2(UserRepository userRepo){
  return  new CommandLineRunner() {
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
      User u = new User();
      u.setName("Some random name");
      Address a1 = Address.builder()
          .street("First Street")
          .city("first city")
          .state("first state")
          .pincode("100001")
          .build();
      Address a2 = Address.builder()
          .street("Second Street")
          .city("Second city")
          .state("second state")
          .pincode("200002")
          .build();
      u.setAddresses(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a1, a2)));
      userRepo.save(u);
    }
  };
}
```

When run, if fails with this error:

> GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error
> executing DDL "alter table user_addresses drop foreign key
> FKfm6x520mag23hvgr1oshaut8b" via JDBC Statement

Yet, the final tables are created:
`describe user_addresses`:

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id | int          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| city    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pincode | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| street  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

`describe user`:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Why cannot the jdbc drop the foreign key `user_id` in table `user_addresses`? How to make the jdbc to do so?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: What happens if you run that DDL from a command line client? Do you get a better error message?

Comment: @JoãoDias mysql

Comment: @tgdavies in mysql client, it passes correctly (that is, the foreign key is successfully droped)

Answer (score 0):

"USER" is a reserved word in MySQL and that might be the root cause of the issue. Change the name of the `User` entity or add `@Table` annotation to it and define a different name.

Reference documentation:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html